# Why did Teru Mikami do what he did at the end of Death Note?

Tags: death-note

In the end of Death Note anime, Why did Teru..

> ..kill himself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Death Note Wiki](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Teru_Mikami), the explanation isn't clear and it's different in the anime and the manga.

The event you describe happened in the anime only, so we'll talk about that.

> Light denies any knowledge of Teru. Teru is shocked and stabs himself with a pen which implies that he was upset that his "god" denied his existence and did it out of despair. However, this act also creates a diversion and allows Light to escape the warehouse so Teru could have been trying to help Light all along.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that had always puzzled me a bit but now that makes more sense, I guess Teru was just super devoted to him.